# Qt - QPushButton text formatting

Tags: c++, qt, formatting, button

I have a QPushButton and on that I have a text and and icon. I want to make the text on the button to be bold and red. Looked at other forums, googled and lost my hope. Seems there is no way to do that if the button has an icon (of course if you don't create a new icon which is text+former icon). Is that the only way? Anyone has a better idea?

Comment: I may be a bit late. Perhaps this link http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/31094-QPushButton-with-a-custom-QLabel?p=145160#post145160 will help some one. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You really don't need to subclass to change the formatting of your button, rather use stylesheets e.g.

```
QPushButton {
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Applying this to the button that you want to change will make the buttons text 18pt, bold and red. You can apply via `widget->setStyleSheet()`

Applying this to a widget in the hierarchy above will style all the buttons underneath, the [QT stylesheet](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) mechanism is very flexible and fairly well documented.

You can set stylesheets in the designer too, this will style the widget that you are editing immediately

Answer (score 6):

you make the subclass of "QPushbutton", then override the paint event,
there you modify the text to your wish.

here it is,

```
class button : public QPushButton
    {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    button(QWidget *parent = 0)
        {

        }
    ~button()
        {

        }

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *p2)
        {

        QPushButton::paintEvent(p2);

            QPainter paint(this);
            paint.save();
            QFont sub(QApplication::font());
            sub.setPointSize(sub.pointSize() + 7);
            paint.setFont(sub);
            paint.drawText(QPoint(300,300),"Hi");
            paint.restore();

        }
    };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);


    button b1;
    b1.showMaximized();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I have read that on the internet but have no idea  what I should do. Could you add some details?

Comment: Honestly I don't understand what is written here, but tried to instantiate from your class instead of QPushButton, but it does not make any change.

Comment: I would avoid custom painting, as it will interfere with the style, button sizes etc.
Narek: Did you try with Qt style sheets?

Comment: Have tried {font: 75 10pt "MS Shell Dlg 2"; color: rgb(170, 0, 0)} , but bold does not work. (Size and color work!).

Comment: @Narek, i have updated my code, i thought u only need how to subclass pushbutton, now i have also updated how to use this in main function.

See you need to create the object of custom class button the paint event of button class handles the drawing,there you can draw as many strings as well as icons for the button at desired location

Comment: subclassing and custom drawing is overkill to this, nothing that can't be done through stylesheets

Comment: This is overkill for styling the text but it's a very good starting point when the whole button needs to be styled. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

*Note:
My answer is inspired by the idea from @Петър Петров and the comment from @mjwach.*

You can subclass `QPushButton` and give it two private fields:

- `self.__lbl`: A `QLabel()` instance to hold the rich text. Its background is made transparent and it doesn't catch mouse events.
- `self.__lyt`: A `QHBoxLayout()` to hold the label. The layout margins are set to zero, such that the label's borders touch the button's borders. In other words: we ensure that the label has the exact same size as the button, and is positioned right on top of it.

Finally you have to override the `setText()` method, such that the text ends up in the label instead of the button.

```py
class RichTextPushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, text=None):
        if parent is not None:
            super().__init__(parent)
        else:
            super().__init__()
        self.__lbl = QLabel(self)
        if text is not None:
            self.__lbl.setText(text)
        self.__lyt = QHBoxLayout()
        self.__lyt.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.__lyt.setSpacing(0)
        self.setLayout(self.__lyt)
        self.__lbl.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.__lbl.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)
        self.__lbl.setSizePolicy(
            QSizePolicy.Expanding,
            QSizePolicy.Expanding,
        )
        self.__lbl.setTextFormat(Qt.RichText)
        self.__lyt.addWidget(self.__lbl)
        return

    def setText(self, text):
        self.__lbl.setText(text)
        self.updateGeometry()
        return

    def sizeHint(self):
        s = QPushButton.sizeHint(self)
        w = self.__lbl.sizeHint()
        s.setWidth(w.width())
        s.setHeight(w.height())
        return s
```

Comment: Adding ```self.__lbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)``` to init helps center the label too

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass a QLabel and completely throw away all of its mouse events (so they reach the parent). 
Then crate a QPushButton, set a layout on it and in this layout insert a QLabel with formatted text. You get a button that contains QLabel and is clickable. (Any Qt Widget can have layout set, including ones that you never ever expected they can.)

Comment: This solution seems to be working pretty well for me!  I had to do QWidget::setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground) to remove the label's background, and I used QWidget::setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents) to cause mouse events to be ignored.  (I think I could subclass the label and alter its event handler or whatever to accomplish that, but I guess the aforementioned widget attribute is good enough.)  Also I had to give the push-button's layout a small left margin (maybe a right one is also needed?) and zeroed top and bottom margins to align the text decently.