# html tags are not working in Qt

Tags: html, c++, qt

I'm learning how to use html and css in Qt programming and I want to change the text of a pushButton using this :

```
ui->pushButton->setText("<b>chert</b>");
```

But it doesn't work correctly. html tags have no effect on it.
How can I make it work?!

Thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990060/qt-qpushbutton-text-formatting

Comment: You may draw a custom label with `QTextDocument`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you can use a label or text document to print the text you want. You should paint it to a pixmap and use the pixmap on your button :

```
QTextDocument doc;
doc.setHtml("<b>chert</b>");
doc.setTextWidth(doc.size().width());

QPixmap pixmap(doc.size().width(), doc.size().height());
pixmap.fill( Qt::transparent );
QPainter painter(&pixmap);
doc.drawContents(&painter);

button->setIconSize(pixmap.size());
button->setIcon(pixmap);
```

An other way to achieve this is to derive from `QPushButton` and draw text yourself via `QPainter` in `paintEvent`. You can find a rich text push button implementation [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Rich_text_pushbutton_implementation).

You can also use [QxtPushButton](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/tip/qxtpushbutton.html) class from libqxt. `QxtPushButton` widget is an extended QPushButton with rotation and rich text support.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this in a pdf about Qt and I wanted to try it, now I found that it's because my Qt is not updated :P  Anyway I learned a lot :)