# How to customize a QPushbutton in Qt code

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Consider I have created a button in "C++ code" named `my_button`:

```
QPushButton* my_button = new QPushButton (tr("OK"));
```

Now I want to manipulate this button as follows:

1. Change the font to *Italic* or **Bold** (e.g., *OK* **OK**)
2. Set a red or blue color for it
3. Make the font bigger/smaller
4. Change its size (height and width)
5. Change its position (to right/left/up/down)

I searched the web mush but couldn't find a way for doing all of the works.
I would thank you if you tell me how to do these.

Comment: you can change it in the properties when designing

Comment: What if I's created it using pure C++ code? I didn't use the Designer.

Comment: oh sorry , html format doesnt work on qpushbutton text, you first have to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852340/two-colours-text-in-qpushbutton

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt - QPushButton text formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990060/qt-qpushbutton-text-formatting)

Comment: Set a red or blue color for it for the color text or background button?

Answer (score 1):

To change the characteristics of the buttons you can use the `font` and `stylesheet`, to move the `move()` function, and to resize the `resize()` function is used. 
You do not need to search the entire web, the best source is always the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html).

```
QFont font = {your Button}->font();
font.setBold(true); //set style bold if is true
font.setItalic(true); //set style italic if is true
font.setPixelSize(20); // Sets the font size to pixelSize pixels.
{your Button}->setFont(font);
//change color
QString Buttonstyle = "QPushButton {background-color: #0000FF,
                       color: red;}");

{your Button}->setStyleSheet(Buttonstyle);
{your Button}->move({posx}, {posy});
{your Button}->resize({width}, {height});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
QString ButtonStye = "{font: 75 12pt \"Tahoma\"";
        "color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"
        "width : 50px;"
        "height: 25px;"
    "}";

my_button->setStyleSheet(ButtonStye);
```

you can change width, height, color abd font's pointsize and family. Qt Limited Support CSS. [Look At Qt Official Page's How CSS Code implement a specific Widget.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html)

and if you put the your widget(QPushButton) to right position, you can use QHBoxLayout or QVBoxLayout for positiong.

Comment: So you say the only way to position a widget (here a *QPushButton*) is using *QH/VBoxLayout*?

Comment: you asked change its position at 5. what you mean about?